# JSF. Restrict direct access to template-client page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I've got a question. In this example i'm trying to make a template that includes template client's code. Here's a code.

Here's template.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:form>
            <ui:include src="template-client.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's template-client.xhtml.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <f:facet name="row">
            <h:commandButton value="template" action="template.xhtml"  />                    
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

And my question is: why when i'm trying to open URL with directly specifying name of template-client.xhtml, i've got XML output with all my source code e.g. name of beans, tags and so on. Is there any way to prevent access to template-client.xhtml directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `.xhtml` pages are not mapped to the [FacesServlet](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html). You have to explicitly define the url mapping in the web.xml. When not mapped to the FacesServlet, they are simply returned without any processing (and thus you see the facelet code).

If you don't want someone to be able to access directly to a resource in a web application, you also have to move it somewhere under the `WEB-INF` folder. I usually put all my templates under this folder (e.g. `/WEB-INF/templates/`).